# You are trying to make me emotional

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

In the course of asking person B to do something (which that person resists, for various reasons) person A is evoking imagery, using flattery or making sentimental appeals with the intention of "moving" (in the sentimental sense) person B. What might be an appropriate, succinct, informal, colloquial rebuke from person B conveying the following message:

*Hey, I can see your game, you are trying to make me agree with you by appealing to my emotions.*

I guess "you are trying to move me" is not correct as the "I was moved (touched)" sense can not be conveyed using this verb form (or can it?).

**update:** As explained in the comments I am looking for an expression that's only (or mostly) applicable to attempts to leverage on somebody's benevolent emotions as opposed to their calculating brain or their "darker" emotions (lust, greed, anger).

Comment: "*You are trying to **manipulate** me*".

Comment: It can also be correct to use "move", though generally when people use a verb like this in a forceful sense, they use a slightly more forceful version, such as "push". "I see you're game. You're trying to push me [to do X]."

Comment: @DanBron tnx but I think "manipulate" does not always carry the connotation of trying to get the other side to become "softer"; one might be manipulated using greed, lust, etc. In other words, they can also be manipulated by an appeal to their logic / calculating part of their brain as opposed to their emotional side.

Comment: _push my buttons_ is a common idiom for evoking an emotional reaction.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about using *emotion* rather than *logic/reason* as a mechanism to ***win*** an argument? What about conjuring up a specific emotional state in the other person for illustrative purposes? Or *therapeutic* purposes?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes using emotion or flattery, and not necessarily an argument; e.g. asking a child to do his homework and then (after explaining logically) saying "you'll do it for Daddy, won't you?". Perhaps "argument" was the wrong word; more like getting somebody to do what you want. I just updated  the question.

Comment: ***Sway*** might work. It has some of the same drawbacks as ***manipulate*** - but not so much, I feel. Or how about ***beguile**?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The phrase guilt-trip comes to mind.** Guilt tripping is using sentiment or emotion to convince the target that you are right. The particular definition (from thefreedictionary):

> guilt′ trip`
> n.
> Informal. a feeling of guilt or responsibility, esp. one not justified by reality.
>
> "I think you should give me your car. It's what your mother would have wanted, after all."
> "You are guilt tripping me!"

**Another appropriate answer is manipulating.** Manipulating is generally using selected pieces of evidence to emotionally or mentally coerce someone into doing what you want them to do. By using shady or potentially abusive arguments, you are manipulating someone.
Definition from thefreedictionary:

> ma·nip·u·late
> To influence or manage shrewdly or deviously: He manipulated public opinion in his favor.
>
> To tamper with or falsify for personal gain
>
> "Oh, I think your hair looks lovely in the messy bun. It has a good 'quickly put together' look while also being attractive."
> "Stop it, you're just manipulating me so I won't re-do my hair before we go out!"

**You could also use the phrase emotional blackmail.** It is very similar to a guilt trip, in that it plays off of a target's emotional guilt to cause them to do something you want of them.

edited to add manipulate definition

Answer (score 1):

You can rebuke the manipulator by telling them:

"I can't be swayed by you ***plucking my heartstrings"***

or "I won't change my mind because of you ***playing my heartstrings"***

Per Dictionary.com, the definition of [heartstrings](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/heartstrings) is:

> 1. the deepest feelings; the strongest affections:
>
> Example: "to tug at one's heartstrings."